# Generate QR Code directly into ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview, zxing

I am generating a QR code with ZXing library in an Android app.

Instead of directly saving it into a file, I want it to go into an ImageView.

Here is my code:

```
String WIFIQRCODE = "";
String SSID = etSSID.getText().toString();
String PASS = etPASS.getText().toString();
String PASSTYPE = sTYPE.getSelectedItem().toString();
WIFIQRCODE =   "WIFI:T:"+PASSTYPE+";S:"+SSID+";P:"+PASS;
//Inform the user the button1 has been clicked
QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
BitMatrix bitMatrix = null;
try {
    bitMatrix = writer.encode(WIFIQRCODE, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300);
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "/sdcard/Images/"+SSID+".png");
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(bitMatrix, "png", file);

} catch (WriterException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to modify it, so that it puts it into an ImageView instead of a file?

Comment: Write to a bitmap instead of a file then imageView.setImageBitmap(QRBitmap)

Answer (score 21):

you will need to get `Bitmap` from `BitMatrix` to set directly image in ImageView do it as:

```
    int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
    int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
   ImageView qr_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrimage);
    qr_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

for more detail you can see Generating [QR Codes with ZXing](http://codeisland.org/2013/generating-qr-codes-with-zxing) for getting Bitmap from bitMatrix

Answer (score 1):

simple way

```
public static Bitmap createQRImage(final String url, final int width, final int height) throws WriterException {
    final BitMatrix bitMatrix = new QRCodeWriter().encode(url, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, Collections.singletonMap(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8"));
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(IntStream.range(0, height).flatMap(h -> IntStream.range(0, width).map(w -> bitMatrix.get(w, h) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE)).toArray(),
            width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

or

```
public static Bitmap createQRImage2(final String url, final int width, final int height) throws WriterException {
    final BitMatrix bitMatrix = new QRCodeWriter().encode(url, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, Collections.singletonMap(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8"));
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(IntStream.range(0, height * width).map(s -> bitMatrix.get(s % width, s / width) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE).toArray(),
            width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

or, because Stream.toArray() allocate the output array dynamically if size unknown, which may cause memory allocation frequently if the array size too large

```
public static Bitmap createQRImage3(final String url, final int width, final int height) throws WriterException {
    final BitMatrix bitMatrix = new QRCodeWriter().encode(url, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, Collections.singletonMap(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8"));
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(IntStream.range(0, height)
                    .flatMap(h -> IntStream.range(0, width).map(w -> bitMatrix.get(w, h) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE))
                    .collect(() -> IntBuffer.allocate(width * height), IntBuffer::put, IntBuffer::put)
                    .array(),
            width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As appose to that,

get the directory to the image file then feed it in to:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

then its simple as

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```